# Clicking on NOT-focused window in python

Tags: python

Well the problem is rather easy to understand. When playing a game, sometimes I need to use autoclicker. So in order to be able to watch some videos on youtube I need to use another monitor & autoclicker.

I wanted to create such autoclicker that would let me send any keyboard/mouse actions to specific window or even process (if it's possible). However I have no idea where to start?

Answer (score -1):

There is a python library called pyautogui you can us it to automate stuff.

Installation

```py
pip install pyautogui
```

your code should look simething like this

```py
import time
import pyautogui
for ctr in range(10):
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Adjust the time based on requirement and [refer this](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more info about the library

Better to use power automate to make things simple

Comment: but is it capable of sending those clicks to other windows, not just the visible one?

Comment: you can have split screen and click on other screen co-ordinates

Comment: yeah but it changes focus, I am seeking for something that would send input independently and without any effect of the focused window.